# Delete column that includes a specific text

Tags: sed, awk, columns, patterns

I was looking for an option to delete a column with a specific text like

"ddd"

```
aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff
1   2   3   4   5   6
2   3   4   5   6   0
```

So that the output looks likes this:

```
aaa bbb ccc eee fff
1   2   3   5   6
2   3   4   6   0
```

I know there is the easy option to delete column 4 and that does the same job, but my *.csv files aren't sorted. Any ideas?

Comment: Can the `ddd` be anywhere or will it always be in the first line? Are you forced to use `sed` or can you use other tools?

Answer (score 8):

`sed` is not the right tool for this.  Try `awk`:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if ($i=="ddd"){n=i-1;m=NF-(i==NF)}} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1+(i==n))printf "%s%s",$i,i==m?ORS:OFS}' file
aaa     bbb     ccc     eee     fff
1       2       3       5       6
2       3       4       6       0
```

This assumes that the string to remove, `ddd`  in this case, appears as a field in the first line.

#### How it works

- `-v OFS='\t'`

  This sets the output field separator to a tab.  If you are using something else, change this.
- `NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if ($i=="ddd"){n=i-1;m=NF-(i==NF)}}`

  This scans through all columns in the first line.  We save the number of the column with `ddd` (minus one) in the variable `n`.

  It also sets `m` to the number of the last column except in the case that `i` is the last column in which case it sets it to `NF-1`.
- `for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1+(i==n))printf "%s%s",$i,i==m?ORS:OFS`

  This prints out each field, skipping over the field in which `ddd` appeared in the first line.

  `i+=1` would increment `i` by one in each loop.  `i+=1+(i==n)` increments `i` by one in each loop except if `i==n` in which case `i` is incremented by 2.  This has the effect of skipping over the right column.

  `printf "%s%s",$i,i==m?ORS:OFS` prints column `i` followed by either a column separator, `OFS`, or a line separator, `ORS`, depending on whether `i` is the last column.

#### Multiple lines

For those who prefer commands like this written over multiple lines:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '

NR==1{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if ($i=="ddd") {
            n=i-1
            m=NF-(i==NF)
        }
    }

{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1+(i==n))
        printf "%s%s",$i,i==m?ORS:OFS
}

' file
```

#### Using comma-separated files

If we want the input and the output to be comma-separated, we need to change both the input-field-separator (with `-F`) and the output-field-separator.   For example, consider this input file:

```
$ cat file2
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff
1,2,3,4,5,6
2,3,4,5,6,0
```

Then use:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if ($i=="ddd"){n=i-1;m=NF-(i==NF)}} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1+(i==n))printf "%s%s",$i,i==m?ORS:OFS}' file2
aaa,bbb,ccc,eee,fff
1,2,3,5,6
2,3,4,6,0
```

Comment: As for me it rather difficult to check is the field last or not so I'd like to offer just shift fields:`awk 'NR=1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="ddd")n=i}{for(i=n;i<NF;i++)$i=$(i+1);NF--}1' OFS='\t' file`

Comment: Plus one, Yup, as soon as I saw 'delimited' in the question I looked for an awk answer.

Comment: I really love your description and I think I got it all, but today i tried with "," as a seperator and it looks like it blows it up. 

`aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff  
1,2,3,4,5,6  
2,3,4,5,6,0`  

`awk -v OFS=',' 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if ($i=="ddd"){n=i-1;m=NF-(i==NF)}} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1+(i==n))printf "%s%s",$i,i==m?ORS:OFS}' file` it doesn't work for me. Have you any explanation for this? 

Output: ,2,3,4,5,6,0, [nils@nils public]#

Comment: @ItsSomethng To do that, one must change _both_ the _input_ and the _output_ field separators.  See updated answer for an example.

Answer (score 5):

This may be possible in `sed` (most things are) but I doubt it will be simpler than using another tool. The easiest approach is to first get the field number you want and then go through the file printing the rest. For example, in Perl:

```
$ perl -lane 'if($.==1){for(0..$#F){$d=$_ if $F[$_] eq "ddd"}} 
              print "@F[0..$d-1] @F[$d+1..$#F]"' file
aaa bbb ccc eee fff
1 2 3 5 6
2 3 4 6 0
```

However, this screws up the formatting. If that is important, [use John1024's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/230785/22222) instead.

Comment: @john1024, I was referring to your kid brother, obviously.

Comment: Yeah, my parents always liked him better.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -a header <file                 # read first line into array "header"
for i in ${!header[@]}               # iterate through array indexes
do
    if [ "${header[i]}" = "ddd" ]    # find column equal the pattern
    then
        n=$[++i]                     # put column number in variable "n"
        break
    fi
done
# print all column except found delimited by <TAB>
cut --complement -f ${n} < <(tr -s ' ' '\t' <6)
```

But if you like it can be done it “just by **sed**” (even it is not optimal)

```
sed "s/\S\+\s*//$(sed 's/\s\+/\n/g;1q' file | sed -n '/ddd/=')" file
```

`\S\+\s*` - Mean 1 column (non-space symbol(s) followed some possible spaces).
`s/<pattern>//<number>` - Substitute just *number*th occurence of *pattern*.
`s/\s\+/\n/g` - Replace each space or block of spaces with `\n`ewline just for
`1q` - first line (header). So its transform header column into lines.
`sed -n '/ddd/=` - print line number where *pattern* exist == No. of column

Comment: A little explanation won't hurt..

Comment: @heemayl Explanation added

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F "\t" -v "Pat=ddd" 'NR == 1 {for( i = 1; i <= NF; i++) Take[ i] = (Pat != $i)} {for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if( Take[ i]) printf $i FS; print ""}' YourFile
```

- print field that are not excluded
- use same separator as input (`-F "\t"`)
- use variable for pattern selection to exclude (`-v "Pat=ddd"`). could easily modified for regex selection if many selection to do
- done with 2 loop to avoid confusion but could be done in one only